# Turning regulator ON/OFF using EN pin (with Zener)

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener, undervoltage

Is it ok to control the EN pin of a regulator (MIC29302) by just simply using a Zener diode?
(i.e. a reverse biased zener from Vin to EN pin and a pulldown 15k resistor to ground also connected to EN.)

Considering small leakage currents of zener when Vin is close to Vz, Is it a good way to avoid regulator operation in undervoltage condition?

In the datasheet EN is shown being directly connected to IN pin in typical application examples.

Comment: The datasheet provides a maximum LOW voltage on the EN pin of 0,8V. I think using a diode you won't provide sufficient voltage difference to reach the LOW voltage on the EN pin.

Comment: You answer implies it works for my purpose? Reading the datasheet, where it gives LOW and HIGH voltage thresholds for EN pin, I think I've asked my question wrong. I shouldn't worry about small currents going through zener to EN, when zener is supposed to be in cutoff mode. And the voltage is all that matters. Right?

Comment: why a Zener? why not simply a voltage divider?

Comment: Right. A voltage divider and Schmitt trigger is best solution. Glad I have an unused channel from the 74LS14 inverter already in use in my circuit.

Comment: by the way, other regulators do have more elaborate Enable inputs, probably even some with hysteresis, and lower dropout voltage. MIC29302 sounds like a good choice only for high currents, and in that case, it almost sounds like a switch-mode power supply would be a better choice.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! _”a reverse biased zener from Vin to EN pin and a pulldown 15k resistor to ground also connected to EN.”_ For future reference, this is what the EE community would classify as a bunch of words and should be replaced with a _schematic_ which is the official language for EEs around the world. I kid you not! The technician at our EMS only spoke three words of English, Yes, No and PWM. Very hard to communicate until we started to draw a schematic and both parties immediately understood what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a trigger circuit. Without hysteresis your devise would flicker. This can be done using some voltage reference and a Schmitt trigger.